# How do I downgrade the ChromeDriver version in protractor

Tags: angular, protractor

We are using Protractor for E2E tests in our Angular app. Without changing any of our code, our deployment is failing with a timeout error. The only thing that seems to be different is the version of the ChromeDriver, which is now 99.0.4844.51.
Is there a way to specify which version of ChromeDriver protractor is using?

We've already tried setting the timeout to a higher number, as described here: https://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts

So I want to exclude the possibility that this is due to the new ChromeDriver version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the way to do it is

> webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 98.0.4758.80

You can find a list of chromedriver versions on [this page](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)